Vlocity / Omni Studio Components not visible in VS Code
I have an developer org. It has OmniScripts OmniDataTransforms and other OmniStudio Components in that org. When I authorize to the org, Omni studio components are not visible in org browser. I tried creating package.xml using the vs code extension, no omniscripts are visible. The Omni Studio components are present in org but not visible in vs Code
I have enabled Omnistudio Metadata under Omnistudio Settings.
I have installed Salesforce extension pack  and Salesforce extension pack (expanded).
I have tried to retrieve omni scripts using package.xml with * operatior.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>OmniScript</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>

I want to retrieve the omni studio components in vs code and run a validation using sf command.
Can someone please help me with it ? Any blogs to understand this behavior is highly appreciated.

refresh the settings page to check if Omnistudio Metadata shows as enabled. maybe you have enabled it but there was some errors in the backend

Also, you need to increase your API version in package xml to at least API version 56.0 and ideally set it to 62.0
